# Is there a way to fill a map of vector in one line

Tags: c++, dictionary, vector, std

I'm filling a map of vector, and I'd like to know if there is a way to do it in one line, instead of creating a temporary variable. I'm doing that :

```
map<string, vector<AnEnum> > myMap;
AnEnum tempEnum;

vector<AnEnum> tempList; tempList.push_back(tempEnum);
myMap["key"] = tempList;
```

I tried to do this

```
myMap["key"] = vector<AnEnum>(tempEnum);
```

But Visual put it in red. I cannot find the good way in C++ to do that. I would know with `new`, but that would create me a pointer. It's not critical, but my C++ curiosity :)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [brace-initialisation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/initializing-classes-and-structs-without-constructors-cpp?view=vs-2019) (since C+11) you can do this:

```
myMap["key"] = { AnEnum{} };
```

which will implicitly create a vector containing 1 `AnEnum` element for the key `"key"`. You can have more elements by having more elements separated by commas (e.g. `{ AnEnum{}, AnEnum{} }`) if you want.

---

You can also create the whole map using brace-initialisation in one go if you want:

```
std::map<std::string, std::vector<AnEnum>> mymap = {
        { "key1", { AnEnum{} } },
        { "key2", { AnEnum{} } }
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

```
std::map<std::string, std::vector<AnEnum>> myMap;
myMap.insert(std::make_pair("key", std::vector{AnEnum{}}));
```

And

```
myMap["key"]= std::vector{AnEnum{}};
```